The longtime stated that this winter La Niña is expected to develop and hang on through the season
Is "the longtime" grammatically correct? I think it refers to Farmers’ Almanac Canada, but maybe I am wrong about it. If it's grammatically correct, then I could use "the precise" to substitute Farmers’ Almanac Canada? Thank you in advance!

Winter in Alberta can bring some serious bouts of cold and snowy conditions and an extended outlook from Farmers’ Almanac Canada is hinting at one timeframe being especially harsh.
The longtime stated that this winter La Niña is expected to develop and hang on through the season, and by blending the effects of La Niña into its proprietary formula, the winter of 2024-25 should see below-normal temperatures for about two-thirds of the nation, from east of the Rockies to Ontario."


It makes no sense to me, not the original sentence and not your remark about "the precise".

It's an error. They may have been thinking of 'long term' [weather forecast] which is what Farmer's Almanac publications have claimed to produce since 1819.

"Longtime" is only typically used as an adjective. A noun or noun phrase has been accidentally omitted. We can only guess, but it would refer to Farmers’ Almanac Canada; maybe something like "The longtime source for planting decisions stated...." No, you can't use other adjectives without their noun referents like this either.
Places where you can use an adjective to do the work of a noun are usually limited to contexts in which the noun is very close by and clear, and typically multiple adjectives are being contrasted as varieties of that noun: "You take the left path and I'll take the right" (repetition of the noun is understood and omitted) or "sort the candies into reds and greens" (a temporary, informal noun-version is created from the adjectives). Sometimes repeated use can formalize these "noun versions" into official, recognized nouns, like "a heavy" to mean a thug or "a tall" to mean a size of coffee cup, etc. But there's no such usage so far for "a longtime" or "a precise."
